# Excluding jars coming from dependency

Tags: java, maven

I am writing a class where I have to use one utility class that is defined in some other artifact.
So I added that artifact in pom as a dependency.

Now while packaging I am getting a number of jars added in my lib coming from the added dependency.
I want to remove those jars from my lib.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Maven documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html#dependency-exclusions)

Comment: The answer to your question depends on the method you use for packaging your lib. Do you use the shade maven plugin? https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transitive Dependency How do i exclude. -- Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45607615/transitive-dependency-how-do-i-exclude-maven)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to check whether you really do not need the other JARs. Maybe they are called by the utility class that you use.

If not, you have essentially two possibilities:

- exclude all the transitive dependencies by using Maven exclusions.
- copy the code that you call into your project.

Comment: Thanks for the Suggestion. 
There are 80+ jars coming through transitive dependency.  So I excluded all jars first and then added dependency for all jars which are required.

e.g: 

         <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>*</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>